# Camera sensor to accept or reject the position in which a component is kept on a machine

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, raspberry-pi, camera

The factory where I work has a hole punching and labeling machine, that basically needs to punch holes and stick labels onto a plastic container. The most important aspect is that the container needs to be placed in the correct orientation or else the holes and labels will be made on the wrong side.

This operation is highly dependant on the operators. The container cannot be modified to incorporate any foolproof mechanism as the die has already been made. The container does have a branding image molded onto it. I was wondering if I could use a controller and a webcam placed in a position to identify the branding logo. If the logo is identified then the container is in the correct orientation else the machine stops and raises an alarm. I have some basic knowledge of electronics and programming but need help with direction.

Would a raspberry pi be a useful controller to work with industrial machines or are there powerful boards that can be used for this purpose, would not want to invest in a plc though. I just want to test the idea out and check if I can make something work first.

Edit 1:

The color of the molded branding is the same as that of the background which is black.

Thanks for your time and support!

Comment: You would be wise to investigate image recognition software first.  That would tell you what system resources you need.  That's not simple software to build and may be challenging just to integrate.  That said, you'd probably want some sort of PLC for an industrial environment.  It's essentially just a microcontroller with isolated inputs and outputs.  You could try to build a properly isolated microcontroller from some beginner kit, but even if you succeed, it could be really awkward talking to the insurance guy after a worker loses an arm or something.

Comment: For operation on a dangerous machine in an industrial environment, you may need an engineer to sign off on the design.

Comment: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Comment: The brighter and more colourful the logo is, the easier this will be.

Comment: Hussain, You may be better off avoiding image recognition software and learning about optics. There are several very useful factors (significant differences between impacts on polarization from a reflected optical source; very simple and quite robust changes in the fourier plane [spatial filtering]; astigmatic lens coupled with 45\$^\circ\$ quad-detector as used in CD and DVD drives everywhere) that would make this a slam-dunk and easily done using technology 50 yrs old or relatively cheap these days. Likely still better results than using imaging software, today, in fact. Learn some stuff.

Comment: Hussain, I didn't list all of the options, either. I consider people who rely on image processing software for some problem like this as the same as a person with a chainsaw who sees everything as a tree (because they only have one tool they know how to apply and cannot think beyond it.) Spread your wings, learn an array of ideas, develop some tests and get some results, then decide what to apply and how to apply it. There's no escaping "being well-informed" when solving problems. We all want quick fixes handed on a platter to us. But it's better to educate yourself.

Comment: @jonk Thanks for your comments, it is interesting to know that technology used in CD roms can be useful. I would like to know if there are any off-the-shelf sensors that can be used directly ?

Comment: @KH thank you for taking the time to comment. The machines are actually not dangerous at all they are pretty basic and do not require any safety features. Nobody is losing an arm or leg :P. since I have knowledge about arduinos and raspiberry pi's I was wondering if I could build something with these. I have seen projects online where people create image detection software that can be run on RPI. Another problem that I face is that the logo that is molded on the conatiner is the same color (black) as the background.

Comment: Yes, an rpi and Webcam running Opencv would/could work. Its not ideal and may take more time and effort and trial/error than doing a professional setup.

Comment: @Hussain I can't suggest a COTS solution. I think your situation will require knowledge and not ignorance. COTS solutions rely upon the vendor to do all of the hard work of applying deep knowledge about a situation. That's not your case. This will require ***you*** to have deep knowledge and to apply hard work, I imagine. No easy way out. The cd-rom technique may, or may not, be useful. It depends a great deal on the predictability of the lens to surface distance among other things. The Fourier plane method coupled to the cd-rom technique would be brilliant. But it takes knowledge to apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an industrial project use industrial hardware.

- It will work on standard 24 V supply.
- It will be "hardened" against accidental short circuits, reverse connection, etc.
- It will probably be waterproof and washable. (Check the IP rating.)
- It will work - if you select the right one.
- Others will know how to fix it if it breaks or you leave the company.
- It will be configurable with the manufacturer's software by anyone with reasonable industrial controls knowlege.
- Spare parts will be available.

Most of the industrial sensor manufacturers including Cognex, Keyence, Sick, Omron, ifm, etc., make low-end vision sensors that can be taught an image and give a simple pass/fail inspection result.

> ... would not want to invest in a plc though.

Micro PLCs are available from all the major manufacturers such as Siemens (LOGO!), Allen-Bradley, Mitsubishi, etc., with, typically, 8-in, 4-out arrangements for about €100 / $100. Once you get going on these you'll never look back. Raspberry Pi (note capitals) could be a disaster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs, I agree that a Pi or Arduino would not stand up for everyday use at a factory and might end up creating more harm than good. I did not know that Micro PLCS existed at a lower cost. Learning Ladder logic used in the PLCs might be the only challenge then. I think it will also be safer to get help from the manufacturers in terms of wiring an setup of the devices.